# How do I shared a schema between templates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas

I'm using Jinja templates that depend on other Jinja templates so I MUST use a schema to import them

This is all my schema has in it:

```
#top-level-template1.jinja.schema
imports:
- path: sub-template.jinja
```

Then in my top level template I have this:

```
# top-level-template1.jinja
resources:
  - name: myresource
    type: sub-template.jinja
```

I want create multiple top level templates that use the same sub template (`top-level-template1.jinja`, `top-level-template2.jinja`, `top-level-template2.jinja`, etc).

Do I seriously have to create a schema file for every one of those? Can I share the same schema between them somehow? I would feel stupid copying it a bunch of times and just giving it a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Although is only possible to import templates using schemas, a workaround can be using a [configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#importing_the_template) to import all the templates needed, with the possibility to mix Jinja and Python templates.

```
# configuration.yaml

imports:
- path: template-a.jinja
- path: template-b.py

resources:
- name: some-name
  type: template-a.jinja
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-a

- name: another-name
  type: template-b.py
  properties:
    zone: us-east1-b
```

If this workaround doesn't suit your needs, maybe you can file a [feature request to have this implemented](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187078&template=1163257).

Comment: Im using jinja templates though not config files. you cant pass arguments to config files from the command line like you can with jinja templates (using `--properites`)

Comment: If this doesn't suit your specific needs, maybe is best to file the feature request to have it implemented.